# Numeric answer for PID command

Tags: matlab, simulink, pid-controller

I used a Simulink PD model and used values:

```
P=100; D=10; N=100
```

The input I am giving is

```
 [0;0;0]-[0.05*(10-t);0.04*(10-t);0.03*(10-t)] where t=1:10
```

I get numeric values from the simulation.

I am trying to implement the same in script file but I get answer in transfer function format. I want the answer to be in numeric form like that from Simulink, Here is my MATLab code:

```
for t = 1:10
T_d = [0;0;0];
T_o = [0.05*(10-t);0.04*(10-t);0.03*(10-t)];
T_e = T_d-T_o;
C = pid(100,0,10,100)

T_u=T_e*C

end
```

Kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`lsim`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lsim.html) function:

```
t = 1:0.01:10;
T_o = [0.05*(10-t);0.04*(10-t);0.03*(10-t)];
T_d = zeros(size(T_o));
T_e = T_d - T_o;
C = pid(100,0,10,100);
res = zeros(size(T_e));
for k=1:size(T_e,1)
   res(k,:) = lsim(C,T_e(k,:),t);
end
plot(t,res)
```

[image]